# Flyway clean command failing on snowflake with ASSOCIATE_SEMANTIC_CATEGORY_TAGS' does not exist or not authorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway, redgate

We are getting error during flyway clean command on snowflake instance with error ASSOCIATE_SEMANTIC_CATEGORY_TAGS' does not exist or not authorized.

However this is snowflake provided stored procedure which we didn't own this,and it's not a part of any schema.

Below is the StackTrace

024-02-27T14:12:10.5828869Z Message    : SQL compilation error:
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5829911Z Procedure '..**ASSOCIATE_SEMANTIC_CATEGORY_TAGS**' **does not exist or not authorized.**
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5830338Z
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5831459Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Schema.clean(Schema.java:123) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5832649Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.lambda$doCleanSchema$3(DbClean.java:216) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5833975Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:55) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5835289Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.doCleanSchema(DbClean.java:215) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5836784Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.cleanSchema(DbClean.java:208) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5837880Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.cleanSchemas(DbClean.java:196) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5839210Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.clean(DbClean.java:112) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5840542Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.clean(DbClean.java:90) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5841707Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.clean(DbClean.java:76) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5842839Z    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.clean(DbClean.java:67) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5844539Z    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doClean(Flyway.java:367) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5845578Z    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$400(Flyway.java:56) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5846573Z    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3.execute(Flyway.java:214) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5847475Z    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3.execute(Flyway.java:211) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5848448Z    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:207) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5849503Z    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.clean(Flyway.java:211) ~[flyway-core-8.5.0.jar!/:?]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5850377Z    at com.varian.acdp.flyway.executor.AcdpFlywayExecutor.clean(AcdpFlywayExecutor.java:75) ~[classes!/:2.0]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5851227Z    at com.varian.acdp.flyway.FlywayUtil.runFlyWay(FlywayUtil.java:30) ~[classes!/:2.0]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5852058Z    at com.varian.acdp.flyway.SnowflakeFlywayApp.run(SnowflakeFlywayApp.java:80) ~[classes!/:2.0]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5853431Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar!/:3.0.6]
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5854151Z    ... 13 more
2024-02-27T14:12:10.5855061Z Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: